# What's the Python analogue of fileinput.input() for output?

Tags: python, file, stdout

[`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) allows to simply loop over all lines in either a list of input files provided via `sys.argv[1:]` or `sys.stdin` if the former is empty.

Is there a similarly simple way to output to the last argument if given and `sys.stdout` otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `argparse` module and add a commandline argument like this:

```
parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
                    default=sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Indeed - but is there any way to have [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) handle all but the last argument first, i.e. I'd like to support a syntax such as `myprog infile1 infile2 infile3 outfile`?

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: If the number of input files is always 3, you can add positional arguments. If the number of input files is not fixed, whether there is an `outfile` is not determinable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the final argument is a file, in which case it is an input so set the output to `sys.stdout`, otherwise open a new file with that name as output and remove it from `sys.argv`.

Alternatively just use sys.stdout and let your users use `> filename` to store to a file.